# Can't parse "16" as an integer

Tags: java

I've retrieved the string `"16"` over http.  But when I try to parse it to an integer:

```
Integer.parseInt(result);
```

I get this:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "16"
```

Could it be something to do with my encoding?  Surely then it wouldn't show up as `"16"` but something unreadable?

EDIT ok I omitted the code originally since there's too much of it.  Here's a precis:

```
URL url = new URL(myurl);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.connect();
is = conn.getInputStream();
String contentAsString = readIt(is);
return contentAsString;
```

[`readIt()` method](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html).

```
public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Reader reader = null;
    reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");        
    char[] buffer = new char[len];
    reader.read(buffer);
    return new String(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code that produce this error ?

Comment: Are you using quotes to delimit the string literal, or are there actually quotes in the string itself? Show us **the exact string literal** that you're passing to `parseInt()`.

Comment: Are you try to do `int myInt = Integer.ParseInt("theString")`????

Comment: What does this print?  System.out.println("x" + result + "x")

Comment: I'm guessing that the value is surrounded by quotes.

Comment: Are you getting input like this:

String result = "16";
Or like this:

String result ="\"16\"";
A more complete code snippet to show your problem would help.

Comment: If it had quotes the error message would show `""16""` ... FYI

Comment: @MattBall Actually the error would be `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""16""`

Comment: Print the numeric values of charAt(0) and charAt(1).

Comment: @mdarwin - use your debugger, look at what is actually in `result`

Comment: You say you retrieved it through http. Probably your problem lies there.

Comment: @jarmod the result is x5x

Comment: `x5x`?  When parseInt is complaining about "16"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As various people pointed out, it turns out there were a load of unprintable characters after the 16.

The trim() or replace() options both worked, but the problem lay in the method I copied from the android developer training page!

When I replaced it with something based on

```
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
```

The problem went away.

To be fair I'm not really interested in spending hours re-inventing the wheel doing input stream manipulation since I have an app to write.  I just wanted to turn a stream into a String and used the first piece of code which worked, or seemed to.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Integer.parseInt(result.trim());
```

Probably you have whitespace character in the end. Have a look at [these characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29).

`'\u001C','\u001D','\u001E','\u001F'` give exactly the same error.

```
String str = "16\u001C";
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str.trim()));
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str));
```

Comment: At least in Java 7 the error message would not be `"16"` if there was trailing whitespace or a line delimiter; just tested it.

Comment: @Brian Roach Please see update above.

Comment: This works, but to my mind is treating the symptoms.

Comment: @Alex Sure but ... if he's getting that back in an HTTP query that's kinda ... odd.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
Integer.parseInt(result.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
```

Comment: this works, but I am not sure if it should be used by OP, depends on the requirement. in case an invalid string (by user input i.e) will throw a runtime exception or do something else, this will  make almost all strings valid.

Comment: It is about the rest of your code. In this question problem was that you were passing characters other than digits to `parseInt`. This is how you solve it. I don't have your full code so I can't say anything about other operations.

Comment: This works, but to my mind is treating the symptoms

Answer (score 2):

> I've retrieved the string "16" over http

No you haven't. You've retrieved a string containing "16" and some other junk characters, possibly `nul` for example. Dump the entire string byte by byte and you will see. You need to fix that at source.

Comment: right, a loop over result.getBytes() revealed a load of useless (and unprintable) characters.

Comment: @mdarwin well, that's your problem.